# How do I resolve unused argument in nrow?

Tags: r

I am new to R. I keep getting an error:
Error in nrow(col1, col2) : unused argument (col2)

This is my code:

```
check_even = function(df, col1, col2, res){
  df[, res]=  for (i in nrow(col1, col2)) {
    if (df[i, col1] %% 2 == 0) {
      df[i, col2] = df[i, col1] * 2 
    } else {
      df[i, col2] = df[i, col1] * 3
    }
  }
  return (df) 
}
```

Was it something that I missed in my nrow?

Comment: `nrow` excepts a single argument `x` which should be an array, vector, or data frame. In this case, you probably want to pass `nrow(df)`. `nrow` on those column names even if just passing a single argument doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hi. I need both the row data in col1 and col2 to pass through the function, hence I used the for loop function. Is the writing of that incorrect? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do what you want with a single `ifelse` statement:

```
df$col2 <- ifelse(df$col1 %% 2 == 0, df$col1 * 2, df$col1 *3)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. i still got the same error message. is it in the nrow?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure at what output you wanted, but based on the other answers I think this could be what you are looking for:

```
set.seed(123)
df_test = data.frame(INT1 = sample(x = c(1:10), size = 10), INT2 = sample (x= c(20:100), size = 10, replace = FALSE))

check_even = function(df, col1, col2, res){
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if(df[i, col1] %% 2 == 0) {
      df[i,res]<- (df[i, col1] * 2)
    } else {
      df[i,res]<- (df[i, col1] * 3)
    }
  }
  return (df) 
}

check_even(df_test, "INT1", "INT2", "RESULT")

   INT1 INT2 RESULT
1     3   88      9
2    10   76     20
3     2   28      4
4     8   91     16
5     6   45     12
6     9   26     27
7     1   61      3
8     7   98     21
9     5   55     15
10    4   62      8
```

I used `set.seed` to make it reproducible. I changed `df[,res]` to `df[i,res]` so it writes each result to that row. Rather than having the `for` write to `df[i,res]`, I had the `if` or `else` statement write to it. Additionally in the `for` statement, it's now `1:nrow(df)`. Otherwise the `i` will only be given a single number, meaning it will only run row 10 in this sample, rather than running 1, 2, 3, etc. I'm not exactly sure what `col2` is supposed to do in your function, so I left that out.

I'd say you did a great job at trying to create your own function being new to R! Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Hi this really helped! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Please provide next time a reproducible dataset (e.g. with `dput()`).

**Update:**

```
df_test = data.frame(INT1 = sample(x = c(1:10), size = 10), INT2 = sample (x= c(20:100), size = 10, replace = FALSE))

df_test$result = ifelse(df_test$INT1 %% 2 == 0, df_test$INT1 * 2, df_test$INT1 * 3)

   INT1 INT2 result
1     9   86     27
2     7   26     21
3     8   51     16
4     1   57      3
5    10   30     20
6     4   66      8
7     5   55     15
8     2   45      4
9     6   71     12
10    3   41      9

df_test
```

Comment: Hi thanks for helping. I used an the following dataset: df_test = data.frame(INT1 = sample(x = c(1:10), size = 10),
                     INT2 = sample (x= c(20:100), size = 10, replace = FALSE)) 
df_test

Comment: Hi, thanks for the above! I am actually trying to learn how to create functions. Is it possible to get the same results by creating a function?